# SAPUI5 selection change event issue in multi select list

Tags: sapui5

I've a popover component and I added a multi-select list inside of it. I would like to set checked property to true for all items in case of the first item of list is selected. But selectionChange event works for every item's selection event. So, index value of the for loop always starts with zero. What should I do in this situation? Thanks for your suggestions.

Here is my part of a code and screenshot of image;
[image url](https://ibb.co/g8eFCx)

```
new sap.m.List('statusTypesList', {
                            mode: 'MultiSelect',
                            selectedKeys: " ,1,2,3",
                            includeItemInSelection: true,
                            selectionChange: function(oEvent) {
                                var keyValues = "";
                                var itemArray = oEvent.oSource.getItems();
                                if(itemArray[0].getSelected()==true){                                      
                                  for (var i = 0; i < itemArray.length; i++) {
                                    oEvent.oSource.setSelectedItem(itemArray[i], true, true);
                                  }
                                }
                            }                                
                        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the item that fired the event is the first one in your list. Something like this:

```
function(oEvent) {
   var changedItem = oEvent.getParameter('listItem');
   if(changedItem isTheFirstItem){
      //Where 'isTheFirstItem' is the condition you define to identify your first item
      var keyValues = "";
      var itemArray = oEvent.getSource().getItems();
      if(itemArray[0].getSelected()==true){                                      
         for (var i = 0; i < itemArray.length; i++) {
         oEvent.getSource().setSelectedItem(itemArray[i], true, true);
      }
   }
}
```

Define the condition you want in the `if(changedItem isTheFirstItem)` statement

Try this condition, maybe it works: `if(changedItem === oEvent.getSource().getItems()[0])`
If not, just build your own condition to check if it is the first one or not

**NOTE:** User `getSource()` to get the source from the event. It is always better than accessing the object directly

Comment: thanks for your help. But I'm facing with the same problem. selectionChange event of the List works for in every multi-list item selected. Here is the screenshot of my code link https://ibb.co/mhN45H Where am I doing mistake ?

Comment: I've solved that issue like this: if(changedItem === firstItem && firstItem.getSelected()==true){
                                      oEvent.getSource().getItems().forEach(function(item) {
                                          item.setSelected(true);
                                      });
                                    }